# Cinnamon desklet does not pick up changes

Tags: javascript, cinnamon

I want to write a Cinnamon desklet, but I do not get the development cycle right.
I started with a hello world desklet.
Files are in ~/.local/share/cinnamon/desklets/hello@world

desklet.js

```
const Desklet = imports.ui.desklet;

function HelloDesklet(metadata, desklet_id) {
    this._init(metadata, desklet_id);
}

HelloDesklet.prototype = {
    __proto__: Desklet.Desklet.prototype
    ,_init: function(metadata, desklet_id) {
        Desklet.Desklet.prototype._init.call(this, metadata);
        this._cont = new St.Label();
        this._cont.set_text("Hello, world!");
        this.setContent(this._cont);
    }
}

function main(metadata, desklet_id) {
    return new HelloDesklet(metadata, desklet_id);
}
```

metadata.json

```
{
    "uuid": "hello@world",
    "name": "Hello World",
    "description": "Say hello",
    "prevent-decorations": false
}
```

So far everything is running fine, I can add the desklet and it show up the Hello World message.

Now if I change to code to write "Hello, new world!" instead of "Hello, world!", remove the desklet and add it again, the old message still shows up.
How can I make Cinnamon pick up my changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer: [Desklet modifications not taken into account at reload](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/7348).

> This is a known issue with Cinnamon 3.6, its been fixed in Cinnamon 3.8.
>
> For now you will have to restart Cinnamon, sorry.

Check your Cinnamon version.

Other alternative is to restart Cinnamon (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> or via `Looking Glass`/`Melange`).

Comment: My cinnamon version is 3.6.7. Looks like I am encountering the bug you describe.

Comment: Yes... I too am on `3.6.7`. So I have to force restarts to get any Desklet(s) to update...